# REGEX to match only VALID EXCEL COLUMNS (A-XFD)

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Ok, I have ANOTHER REGEX question for everyone.

I have a field that has multiple validation steps. The first step is to ensure it isn't blank, second is to ensure that only between 1 and 3 CAPITAL LETTERS are entered, and third, to ensure it doesn't contain "[" (an opening bracket will denote a function in this scenario and we skip validation). All of this works. Now, I have to ensure that the value being entered is only a valid Excel Column Reference. Valid Excel Columns can be the letters A - XFD.

I am currently using:

```
if (checkValue !==""){   //check for not blank
    if ((checkValue.match(/^[A-Z]{1,3}$/) === null) && (functionCheck === false) && (validateColumnRange(rangeFrom))) { //check for only 1 - 3 alpha chars & run function check (function looks for "["), and run function check to validate column range

    //do A - XFD validation here

    }
}
```

any further direction will be much appreciated as I have been through regex tuts for hours now and am lost.

I had been given help on a similar issue in the past and my poor attempt to emulate the function that was provided then is as follows:

```
function validateColumnRange(valueRange) {
    if (typeof valueRange !== "string" || !valueRange.length)
        return false;
    var startIndex = valueRange.search(/[\d+]/);
    var column = valueRange.substring(0, startIndex).toUpperCase();
    return (column >= "A" && column <= "XFD");
}
```

it doesn't work...please help

Comment: If you check the input is only 3 letters, why also check there isn't any `[`?

Comment: A - XFD is valid, but so is any function contained in square brackets, so 

[startColumn] would also be a valid entry.

Comment: Here is the full list of validation rules:

checkValue must:
NOT be blank,
Can be a function contained in [],
IF NOT A FUNCTION: Can ONLY contain UPPERCASE ALPHA, and
MUST BE A VALID EXCEL COLUMN REFERENCE (Letters A - XFD)

Comment: The check for "[" actually occurs first, and sets a flag (functionCheck), so ALPHA validation only runs if that function validation fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've already determined that the value is 1-3 alphabetic characters, how about:

```
(column.length < 3 || column <= "XFD")
```

Any value with 2 or less letters should be acceptable, and for the case of three letters, alphabetic comparison is adequate.

Comment: I actually used:

    if (valueCheck > "XFD")
        fieldFailed = true;

Comment: I think the length check might yet be necessary, unless I'm misunderstanding you, since "Z" > "XFD", alphabetically.

Comment: Awesome catch @femtoRgon, I would give you extra votes if I could, you caught that right before a release, LOL. And for the record, you were correct, with the logic I had, "Z" was failing because  "Z" > "XFD" as you said. Now, it works properly, and the "Z" passes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex expression:

```
/^[A-XFD]+$/
```